# Hibernate "IN" clause as ALL instead of ANY

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I'd like to start by apologizing for my unfamiliarity with Hibernate.  I'm only recently getting into it and am far from an expert.

I have three tables:  Contract, Products, and a link table between them to define a many to many relationship.

I'm trying to write an HQL query to return all contracts that contain a *range* of products.  Unfortunately, the `IN` syntax works like an `Any` instead of an `All`.  So if I want all contracts that have ProductA, ProductB, and ProductC, the `IN` keyword will return me contracts that have any individual one of those products, instead of contracts that have all of them.

How should I structure my HQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you expecting `IN` to behave like a `AND`? To my knowledge, `IN` is a kind of `OR`, not a `AND`. `IN` might thus not be what you're looking for. Have a look at Hibernate's [Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) and especially:

> - HQL functions that take collection-valued path expressions: `size()`, `minelement()`, `maxelement()`, `minindex()`, `maxindex()`, along with the special `elements()` and `indices` functions that can be quantified using some, all, exists, any, in.
>
> [...]
>
> The SQL functions any, some, all, exists, in are supported when passed the element or index set of a collection (elements and indices functions) or the result of a subquery (see below):
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> from Show show where 'fizard' in indices(show.acts)
> ```

Comment: So what would I be looking for?

Comment: Can you elaborate how the above query would resolve OP's question?`indices()` will not return property values for entity collection elements AFAIK; and even if it did that won't ensure that ALL products in question are in the collection.

Comment: Anybody knows if there is a way to use the all operator?
to do something like:
SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 > ALL (SELECT s1 FROM t2);

Answer (score 2):

For more than 2000 ids at in clause use a subquery like `[from group where groupid in(select id from elemtable)]`

Otherwise use criteria to overcome the stackoverflow error.

Example:

```
 Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();

 Criteria criteriaEaquals = session.createCriteria(Elements.class);
 criteriaEaquals.add(Restrictions.in("elementId", elemIds));
 criteriaEaquals.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("type")));
 List list = criteriaEaquals.list();

 session.close();
 System.out.println("typelistis--->"+list.toString());

 return list;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [group by / having](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping):

```
select c
  from Contract c join c.products p
 where p.name in ('A', 'B', 'C')
 group by c.id, // list ALL Contract properties
 having count(*) = 3
```

Alternatively you can use a [subquery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries) to avoid listing all properties in `group by`:

```
from Contract c where c.id in (
select c.id
  from Contract c join c.products p
 where p.name in ('A', 'B', 'C')
 group by c.id
 having count(*) = 3
)
```

Obviously "3" will have to be replaced with the actual number of product names you supply in  `in` clause.

Comment: Wouldn't it return contracts that have 3 associated products one of which is either A, B or C?

Comment: No, it won't. It would, however, return contracts that have, say, products A, A and B associated with them; if that's the case (relationship allows duplicates) the only way to resolve this would be to generate nested query with 3 explicit joins.

Comment: Ok I just tested our queries. Yours selects all contracts that have at least A,B,C among their products (so it will select ABCD and XYZABC), mine selects exactly ABC. It is not clear from the question which one is needed, so both are good for different tasks.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your earlier comment then. Yes, my queries will return all contracts that have A,B,C products whether or not they have some other products also associated with them. That's what I think OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In the [blog](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-write-many-to-many-search-queries-in-mysql-and-hibernate/) I went over such hibernate queries, take a look at example #4.

Here is a snapshot (replace Articles with Contracts and Tags with Products):

```
String[] tags = {"Java", "Hibernate"};
String hql = "select a from Article a " +
                "join a.tags t " +
                "where t.name in (:tags) " +
                "and a.id in (" +
                    "select a2.id " +
                    "from Article a2 " +
                    "join a2.tags t2 " +
                    "group by a2 " +
                    "having count(t2)=:tag_count) " +
                "group by a " +
                "having count(t)=:tag_count";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameterList("tags", tags);
query.setInteger("tag_count", tags.length);
List<Article> articles = query.list();
```

Comment: `group by a` is illegal: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping

Comment: You can write "group by a.id" it would be the same, but current one also works fine, just tested it under MySQL.

Comment: MySQL is not exactly known for its strict treatment of `group by` clause. Try the same trick on Postgres or Oracle :-) `group by a.id` would be equally illegal because SQL standard does not allow you to have non-aggregated columns in `select` clause with aggregate function unless they are also in `group by` clause. In your case article name would not be. Mind you I'm not saying your query is bad; just that you'll need to explicitly list all the columns.